# (SyntaxError) mix.exs:50:7: syntax error before: '{'

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

I am trying to add the mnemonic_slugs library into my mix.exs file but I keep getting the error

```
    ** (SyntaxError) mix.exs:50:7: syntax error before: '{'
    |
 50 |       {:mnemonic_slugs, "~> 0.0.3"}
    |       ^
    (mix 1.15.3) lib/mix/cli.ex:43: Mix.CLI.load_mix_exs/1
    (mix 1.15.3) lib/mix/cli.ex:28: Mix.CLI.proceed/1
```

I am on mac and installed elixir via homebrew. I dont know how to fix this issue.
this is my mix.exs file:

```
defmodule Chat.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :chat,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.14",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application.
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
  def application do
    [
      mod: {Chat.Application, []},
      extra_applications: [:logger, :runtime_tools]
    ]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_), do: ["lib"]

  # Specifies your project dependencies.
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options.
  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.7.7"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 3.3"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
      {:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.19.0"},
      {:floki, ">= 0.30.0", only: :test},
      {:phoenix_live_dashboard, "~> 0.8.0"},
      {:esbuild, "~> 0.7", runtime: Mix.env() == :dev},
      {:tailwind, "~> 0.2.0", runtime: Mix.env() == :dev},
      {:swoosh, "~> 1.3"},
      {:finch, "~> 0.13"},
      {:telemetry_metrics, "~> 0.6"},
      {:telemetry_poller, "~> 1.0"},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.20"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.2"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.5"}
      {:mnemonic_slugs, "~> 0.0.3"}
    ]
  end

  # Aliases are shortcuts or tasks specific to the current project.
  # For example, to install project dependencies and perform other setup tasks, run:
  #
  #     $ mix setup
  #
  # See the documentation for `Mix` for more info on aliases.
  defp aliases do
    [
      setup: ["deps.get", "assets.setup", "assets.build"],
      "assets.setup": ["tailwind.install --if-missing", "esbuild.install --if-missing"],
      "assets.build": ["tailwind default", "esbuild default"],
      "assets.deploy": ["tailwind default --minify", "esbuild default --minify", "phx.digest"]
    ]
  end
end
```

Im on mac and I'm not using a virtual machine, I don't know how to fix this please help, I am very new to phenix I don't know why this is happening all I did was copy and past the command into the mix.exs file.

Comment: You've literally missed a comma.  If you look at all the other deps in front of `{:mnemoinic_slugs . . .}` you'll see a comma at the end of each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what language this is but obviously there is a missing comma:
change this:

```
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.5"}
      {:mnemonic_slugs, "~> 0.0.3"}
```

to this:

```
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.5"},
      {:mnemonic_slugs, "~> 0.0.3"}
```